# Detect and Change with List Comprehension in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

```
def check_LM_CapLetters(nex):
df_found_small = nex[(nex.NAME2.str.endswith('_ja'))|(nex.NAME2.str.endswith('_nein'))] 
nex_new = pd.concat([nex,df_found_small]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
Export_small_LM(df_found_small)
return nex_new
```

This is my data:
[image: Data]

With my code I want to detect LM's with small leters at the beginning. 
Export these in a dataframe and continue with a clean big dataframe. 
The thing is now I just drop these lines, but I want to change these now to capital letters at the beginning:

```
_Nein
```

&

```
_Ja
```

and continue with the complete and correct data.

I might work with regex there?

```
 nex.replace(to_replace=r'^LM_[a-zA-Z0-9_]*_ja$', value="_Ja", regex=True)
```

I tried it like this now, but I think i have t divide the string and then only replace the `_nein` & `_ja`

Comment: You want to filter the rows where `_ja` and `_nein` start in lowercase and then change them to uppercase in this new filtered dataframe? Or make everything in one dataframe?

Comment: do it all in the dataframe i use as input

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to just use `str.replace` and apply to whole column:

```
nex.NAME2 = nex.NAME2.str.replace("_ja","_Ja")
nex.NAME2 = nex.NAME2.str.replace("_nein","_Nein")
```

If you need to keep the ones that are originally lower case separate, do that first and then use `replace`. This assumes that none of those codes start with `"LM_ja...` - but it seems that those names are capitalised anyways.

EDIT: You can also use a more "brute force" method:

```
def fix_names(name):
    if name[-3:]=='_ja':
        return name[:-3]+'_Ja'
    if name[-5]=='_nein':
        return name[:-5]+'_Nein'
    return name

nex.NAME2 = nex.NAME2.apply(fix_names)
```

For tagging, it might be simpler to have a tagging column instead of two dataframes:

```
nex['case'] = 'upper'
nex.loc[(nex.NAME2.str.endswith('_ja')|(nex.NAME2.str.endswith('_nein')),'case']='lower'
```

This way all your data is in one place but you can find `df_found_small` like this:

```
nex[nex.case=='lower']
```

Comment: I just edit something new to my question. Probably have a look at it. The problem is just by your idea its not working out. I think I hvae to split it first..and then replace the last part

Comment: Why is the first solution Jim provided not working?